# How to install GTK3 in Centos 6.2

Tags: centos, gtk

I have Centos 6.2 and I want to install GTK3 to be able to install gitg.

I looked up on Google, and couldn't find anything useful. The thing is people suggest I need to install GTK3 by manually compiling it. But there is a big list of dependencies (and these dependencies also have dependencies I need to mess with, which is a PITA).

Any better suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the package manager? Something like `yum install gtk3 gtk3-devel`?

Comment: @MaxMackie It's not available as a package.

Comment: Hmm, then I think you're only bet is to install it manually the hard way. I haven't double checked to make sure it isn't a package, but usually if it isn't in your OS's repos then you're looking at compiling it from source.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you go with another GUI interface to git, as I am certain GTK3 will be painful to compile/install on CentOS 6. Moreover, if advice is permitted, try to learn git from the CLI; it will prove way more useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `git` are you trying to install? `gitg` is available as a package for Fedora 18, I'd be surprised if it wasn't also available for RHEL 6.

Comment: No, it's not. gitg requires Gnome 3, and CentOs 6.3 has Gnome 2. I just installed it on Fedora 18 and it worked alright!